# ElasticSearch fields not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the inquisitor plugin to query iis logs, but for some reason when i try to reduce the number of the returned fields it doesn't work at all.

This query works as expected:

```
{
 "query": {

    "term":
{ "geoip.country_name" : "ukraine"}  

} }
```

but when i add fields it does not.

```
{
 "fields" : ["port"],
 "query": {

    "term":
{ "geoip.country_name" : "ukraine"}  

}
}
```

Comment: You query looks OK. When you say 'doesn't work at all' is there an error or zero results. Is the field `port` the correct path?

Comment: it shows some results with labels : Foul Source Field value, the field and the value text are empty. yes the port is in correct path, also tried to limit different fields like type, method same result

Comment: Have you disabled the `_source` field? If so, are you storing the field 'port'?

Comment: It's inquisitor error, on head it works fine thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Use _source, instead of fields,

I think 'port' is a nested object, which you cannot get by using 'fields'

so do as,

```
{
        "_source" : ["path"]
}
```

So, your source, only contains path.